# Launch Mailchimp evil popup onclick

Tags: javascript, popup, mailchimp

**Styling**

```
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);display:none;z-index:10000; }
    #mc_embed_signup form{position:fixed; top:10%; left:50%; width:50%; margin-left:-25%; font:normal 100% Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; border-radius:4px; border:none; padding:10px 20px; background-color:#fff; color:#000; text-align:left;max-height:400px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;}
    #mc_embed_signup a.mc_embed_close{background:transparent url(http://downloads.mailchimp.com/img/closebox.png) no-repeat; display:block; height:30px; width:30px; text-indent:-999em; position:absolute; top:-10px; right:-10px; display:none; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://zehava.us3.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post?u=fc807e12a60c9cbaaf5f5616e&amp;id=0707dfe742" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <h2>We want to share with you the newest ZEHAVA creations! Leave us your email address! With this occasion, ZEHAVA offers you a gift: a free recondition of your favorite jewelry.</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
</div>
<a href="#" id="mc_embed_close" class="mc_embed_close">Close</a>    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>  <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fnames = new Array();var ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';
try {
    var jqueryLoaded=jQuery;
    jqueryLoaded=true;
} catch(err) {
    var jqueryLoaded=false;
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if (!jqueryLoaded) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
    if (script.readyState && script.onload!==null){
        script.onreadystatechange= function () {
              if (this.readyState == 'complete') mce_preload_check();
        }    
    }
}

var err_style = '';
try{
    err_style = mc_custom_error_style;
} catch(e){
    err_style = '#mc_embed_signup input.mce_inline_error{border-color:#6B0505;} #mc_embed_signup div.mce_inline_error{margin: 0 0 1em 0; padding: 5px 10px; background-color:#6B0505; font-weight: bold; z-index: 1; color:#fff;}';
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style= document.createElement('style');
style.type= 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet) {
  style.styleSheet.cssText = err_style;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err_style));
}
head.appendChild(style);
setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);

var mce_preload_checks = 0;
function mce_preload_check(){
    if (mce_preload_checks>40) return;
    mce_preload_checks++;
    try {
        var jqueryLoaded=jQuery;
    } catch(err) {
        setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);
        return;
    }
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/jquery.form-n-validate.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
    try {
        var validatorLoaded=jQuery("#fake-form").validate({});
    } catch(err) {
        setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);
        return;
    }
    mce_init_form();
}
function mce_init_form(){
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
      var options = { errorClass: 'mce_inline_error', errorElement: 'div', onkeyup: function(){}, onfocusout:function(){}, onblur:function(){}  };
      var mce_validator = $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate(options);
      $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").unbind('submit');//remove the validator so we can get into beforeSubmit on the ajaxform, which then calls the validator
      options = { url: 'http://mysite.us3.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post-json?u=fcsfse12a6sfsdfsfaf5f5616e&id=0707dfe742&c=?', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    beforeSubmit: function(){
                        $('#mce_tmp_error_msg').remove();
                        $('.datefield','#mc_embed_signup').each(
                            function(){
                                var txt = 'filled';
                                var fields = new Array();
                                var i = 0;
                                $(':text', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        fields[i] = this;
                                        i++;
                                    });
                                $(':hidden', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        var bday = false;
                                        if (fields.length == 2){
                                            bday = true;
                                            fields[2] = {'value':1970};//trick birthdays into having years
                                        }
                                        if ( fields[0].value=='MM' && fields[1].value=='DD' && (fields[2].value=='YYYY' || (bday && fields[2].value==1970) ) ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else if ( fields[0].value=='' && fields[1].value=='' && (fields[2].value=='' || (bday && fields[2].value==1970) ) ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else {
                                            if (/\[day\]/.test(fields[0].name)){
                                                this.value = fields[1].value+'/'+fields[0].value+'/'+fields[2].value;                                           
                                            } else {
                                                this.value = fields[0].value+'/'+fields[1].value+'/'+fields[2].value;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            });
                        $('.phonefield-us','#mc_embed_signup').each(
                            function(){
                                var fields = new Array();
                                var i = 0;
                                $(':text', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        fields[i] = this;
                                        i++;
                                    });
                                $(':hidden', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        if ( fields[0].value.length != 3 || fields[1].value.length!=3 || fields[2].value.length!=4 ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else {
                                            this.value = 'filled';
                                        }
                                    });
                            });
                        return mce_validator.form();
                    }, 
                    success: mce_success_cb
                };
      $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').ajaxForm(options);

              $('#mc_embed_signup').hide();
        cks = document.cookie.split( ';' );
        var show=true;
        for(i=0;i<cks.length;i++){
            parts = cks[i].split('=');
            if( parts[0].indexOf('MCEvilPopupClosed')!= -1 ) show = false;
        }
        if (show){
            $('#mc_embed_signup a.mc_embed_close').show();
            setTimeout( function(){ $('#mc_embed_signup').fadeIn();} , 2000);
            $('#mc_embed_signup a.mc_embed_close').click(function(){ mcEvilPopupClose();});
        }

        $(document).keydown(function(e){
            if (e == null) { 
              keycode = event.keyCode;
            } else { 
              keycode = e.which;
            }
            if(keycode == 27){
                mcEvilPopupClose();
            }
        });

        function mcEvilPopupClose(){
            $('#mc_embed_signup').hide();
            var now = new Date();
            var expires_date = new Date( now.getTime() + 31536000000 );
            document.cookie = 'MCEvilPopupClosed=yes;expires=' + expires_date.toGMTString()+';path=/';
        }

    });
}
function mce_success_cb(resp){
    $('#mce-success-response').hide();
    $('#mce-error-response').hide();
    if (resp.result=="success"){
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(resp.msg);
        $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').each(function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    } else {
        var index = -1;
        var msg;
        try {
            var parts = resp.msg.split(' - ',2);
            if (parts[1]==undefined){
                msg = resp.msg;
            } else {
                i = parseInt(parts[0]);
                if (i.toString() == parts[0]){
                    index = parts[0];
                    msg = parts[1];
                } else {
                    index = -1;
                    msg = resp.msg;
                }
            }
        } catch(e){
            index = -1;
            msg = resp.msg;
        }
        try{
            if (index== -1){
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);            
            } else {
                err_id = 'mce_tmp_error_msg';
                html = '<div id="'+err_id+'" style="'+err_style+'"> '+msg+'</div>';

                var input_id = '#mc_embed_signup';
                var f = $(input_id);
                if (ftypes[index]=='address'){
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-addr1';
                    f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else if (ftypes[index]=='date'){
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-month';
                    f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else {
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index];
                    f = $().parent(input_id).get(0);
                }
                if (f){
                    $(f).append(html);
                    $(input_id).focus();
                } else {
                    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
                }
            }
        } catch(e){
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

The popup is set to launch automatically and the user can exit. I want to also put a link on the site to make the popup show on command.
I have tried:

```
<a onclick="$('#mc_embed_signup, #mc_embed_signup a.mc_embed_close').css('display', 'block');" href="#">Newsletter</a>
```

and the popup is shown but doesn't seem to work properly.
**What is the correct form to launch this so called evil popup when I click on a link?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recently got this code from a client (that they copied from Mailchimp.com)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us8.list-manage.com","uuid":"a56ce123456bdcb7974e9ea2","lid":"4esdr6bd94"}) })</script>
```

This is the Evil-PopUp Code and by adding this to your site you get the popup (modal window) for newsletter-signup when the page loads.

My client wanted this popup to show only when a "Sign up now" button was clicked. So this is what I did.

**First** I added the first script as is to the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
```

**Second** I wrote a function that runs the code from the second script and attached a click event to a button with id #open-popup

```
  function showMailingPopUp() {
      require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start(
  {"baseUrl":"mc.us8.list-manage.com","uuid":"a56ce2128001bdcb7974e9ea2","lid":"1d4c16bd94"}
  ) })
  };

  document.getElementById("open-popup").onclick = function() {showMailingPopUp()};
```

**I thought this was it,** but found out that the Mailchimp script adds a session cookie called "MCEvilPopupClosed" after the user has closed the popup for the first time. If that cookie is set you can not open the popup again (since this popup was only meant to be shown once when the user enters the page).

**The solution to that** was adding this code to delete the cookie when the page loads and also each time the modal close button is clicked (requires jQuery but can of course be written in vanilla Javascript if you like). **EDIT:** According to new comments the cookie key has changed to **MCPopupClosed** from **MCEvilPopupClosed**

```
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
    document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
  });
  jQuery('body').on('click', '.mc-closeModal', function() {
    document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
  });
```

**Now...** the user can open and close the Evil Popup as s/he likes.

**EDIT:** Instead of using my code to clear the cookies you could use the solution from @rok-jaklič below. It's better/simpler then mine. Rest should be the same.

Comment: Just add document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"; to showMailingPopUp and you do not need thouse two jquery calls when document or body loads.

Comment: Thanks @RokJaklič, worked for me only after adding your code.

Comment: what do i add exactly? im trying to implement the same solution. if you can edit the answer to be more cleaner that'd be super helpful.

Comment: @helloworld You would need to add ```MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";``` to the showMailingPopUp() function.  I had a problem with the path being different so you may need to add ;path=/ to the cookie string.

Comment: With your solution, for me the cookie was not being properly set and the popup would not come up, so I needed to add a "path" argument to the cookie like this: `document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";`. It's worth noting that I am adding my popup code to a page other than the root page of the domain.

Comment: I'm adding this to WP's MailChimp Subscriber Popup's code area. When I add both scripts from the generated form the form shows up on page load. However, when I remove the second script and add the second script, nothing happens on click. When I look at the page source "mailchimp" isn't even inserted on the page. Is there a different way to add these scripts to the page?

Comment: @emilyk are you using jQuery? Any console errors? Maybe try the pure js method that  Timothy Lee Russell suggests below my answer?

Comment: I tried both the pure javascript above and the jQurey example below (of course replacing ids with mine). No errors in the console. It seems like Wordpress is stripping the code out because I cannot find any of what I add in the page source.

Comment: @emilyk ok, I am afraid I can't help you very much there, sorry... :/

Comment: Looks like the cookie key has changed to "MCPopupClosed", at least for me.

Comment: @LeopoldKristjansson, Can you help me out? I am getting the same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424600/how-to-display-the-mailchimp-subscribe-popup-form-on-click

Comment: Having the most difficult time getting this to work. Clicking the button does nothing but as soon as the user scrolls the page, the form pops up. Something they changed in their code somewhere, and nothing I try gets around it. Its dumb mailchimp just doesn't have an event to just trigger the damned popup.

Answer (score 6):

This is just a copy of @LeopoldKristjansson answer with the comments from @RokJaklič regarding the cookie integrated and binding the click with jQuery.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showMailingPopUp() {
    require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"obscured","uuid":"obscured","lid":"obscured"})})
    document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";                  
};

$(function() {
    $(".open-popup").on('click', function() { 
        showMailingPopUp();
    });
});

</script>
```

**Html**

```
<div class="open-popup">Open evil popup</div>
```

Comment: I tried full code but still not working. Can you help me out? I am getting in console  "The resource at “http://mc.us5.list-manage.com/subscribe/form-settings?u=e47e…74a0a8b&c=dojo_request_script_callbacks.dojo_request_script0” was blocked because content blocking is enabled."

Comment: @questionbank This code is from 2016 - I would suggest that you confirm with mailchimp that this is the current preferred method. In 4 years, their code will have almost certainly changed, perhaps drastically.

Comment: One of my colleague ask the same question here . If you have a time then please check it once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607025/how-to-display-the-mailchimp-subscribe-popup-form-on-click

Answer (score 4):

I needed to add "path=/" to make this work on every page, because MailChimp sets the cookie to the root domain. My website isn't using jQuery and adding it for such a small functionality isn't worth it. The cookie also wasn't called MCEvilPopupClosed for me, but MCPopupClosed.

Placed in **Head**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMailPopup() {
    document.cookie = "MCPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
    document.cookie = "MCPopupSubscribed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
    require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"],function(L){L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us16.list-manage.com","uuid":"8cb755a469ca9c2a6e87c6502","lid":"b809b6d15b"})});
};
</script>
```

Placed in **Body**

```
<button onclick="showMailPopup()">Click</button>
```

Comment: I've added the deletion of `MCPopupSubscribed` which prevents the pop up from showing up twice.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to expire cookie (adding path was required for it to work on all pages):

```
document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

Answer (score 1):

I was forced to clear 2 cookies to make it work.

```
       document.cookie = "MCPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
       document.cookie = "MCPopupSubscribed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

Comment: This worked for me too after the other solutions wouldn't reopen it, thank you bro!

Answer (score 0):

For the one other person who will try this with Nuxt/Vue.js (or some other system that fails when compiling the `require`), here's what worked for me:

````
```
  export default {
    mounted() {
      this.setupMailchimpPopup() 
    },
    methods: {
      setupMailchimpPopup () {
        var chimpPopupLoader = document.createElement("script");
        chimpPopupLoader.src = '//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js';
        chimpPopupLoader.setAttribute('data-dojo-config', 'usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false');

        var m = {
          baseUrl: "mc.us19.list-manage.com",
          uuid: "xxx",
          lid: "xxx"
        };
        var s = `
          document.cookie = "MCPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
          document.cookie = "MCPopupSubscribed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
          require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function (L) { 
            window._showMailchimpPopup = function() {
              L.start({baseUrl: "${m.baseUrl}", uuid: "${m.uuid}", lid: "${m.lid}"});
            };
          });
        `;
        console.log(s);

        var chimpPopup = document.createElement("script");
        chimpPopup.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));

        chimpPopupLoader.onload = function() {
          document.body.appendChild(chimpPopup);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(chimpPopupLoader);
      },
```
````

Now the popup can be opened with `window._showMailchimpPopup()` from Vue or etc.  It won't open again on a 2nd click unless the page is reloaded.