# how to make onclick event on an id beginning by a # in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mailchimp

Hey guys im trying to trigger the mailchimp modal with a onclick event.

Two things, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430446/launch-mailchimp-evil-popup-onclick) and was able to salvage the following code.

```
        document.getElementById("open-popup").onclick = function() {
            showMailingPopUp();

        };

        function showMailingPopUp() {
            document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
            require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { 
                L.start({ 
                    "baseUrl":"mc.us8.list-manage.com",
                    "uuid":"a56ce2128001bdcb7974e9ea2",
                    "lid":"1d4c16bd94"
                }) 
            })
        };
```

which looks great and all but i get the following console error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

so i wrap the code with a `window.onload = function () {}`

and now have the following

```
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("open-popup").onclick = function() {
            showMailingPopUp();

        };

        function showMailingPopUp() {
            document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
            require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { 
                L.start({ 
                    "baseUrl":"mc.us8.list-manage.com",
                    "uuid":"a56ce2128001bdcb7974e9ea2",
                    "lid":"1d4c16bd94"
                }) 
            })
        };    
    }
```

but im still getting the same error. Here's my html markup as well

```
<section class="hero text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <h1><b>Start Getting Paid for Your Homework</b></h1>
        <h2><b>MAKE REAL USE OF YOUR HOMEWORK</b></h2>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" id="#open-popup-">Join Now</a>
    </div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="separator" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <path d="M0 100 L100 0 L100 100 Z" fill="#fff"></path>
    </svg>
</section>
```

**I precise, the button i need to click have a id beginning by a #**

Comment: remove the # of you "a" tag, it must be  id="open-popup"

Comment: @MTroy amateur move, but still getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`

Comment: you mention "jquery" tag on you post keywords, are you still using it ? i don't see any jquery in your code

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the hashtag from your HTML element

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" id="#open-popup-">Join Now</a>
```

to

```
id="open-popup"
```

The error clearly states: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
So it doesn't find your HTML element

Comment: amateur move, but still getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property onclick of null`

Answer (score 0):

The # before the string "open-popup-",
cause an error because this is a language defined symbol,
used to catch any id with jquery from your DOM.

you have to remove it (i don't know if you can, but must!)

A cheaper alternative, is to check if any id is containing the end occurrence of the name:

**

> EDIT: since your post have been edited, removing jquery usage.

**

In javascript

```
document.getElementById("#open-popup-").addEventListener('click',showMailingPopUp());
```

or with jquery

```
$("[id~='open-popup-']").on("click",  function()
{
    showMailingPopUp();
});
```

Comment: How can I do these with class names instead of id I just tried `getelementsbyclassname` and it won't work

Comment: In you tags, you mention jquery, i just composing with what you say use. Are you using jquery library ?

Comment: for my form validation but that a different piece of code lol, i mustve added that tagg on accident looking at my code from an overview

Comment: ok, edit on your tag,committed, and please avoid to add explanation using answer post... just edit your post is sufficient

Comment: how do i do this with classes instead of id??

Comment: try the updated code, test and it works, without error about the malformed begins id