# How to display the Mailchimp subscribe popup form on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, mailchimp

I am using WordPress. I have to display the Mailchimp subscribe popup on click on the button.

I tried below code but it's not displaying my popup. I checked on google and SO, I found some solution but that is not working.

Would you help me out with this?

```
<ul><li class="open-popup"><a href="#">Subscribe to our mailing list</a></li></ul>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
    <script>
    function showMailingPopUp() {
        //alert("hello");
        require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us20.list-manage.com","uuid":"bd7ed5583d8f567d56a2ed5ec","lid":"007366445e","uniqueMethods":true})})
        document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";                  
    };
    $(function() {
        $(".open-popup a").on('click', function() { 
            showMailingPopUp();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - I wanted a mailchimp popup on-click.

The solution I found was instead of using mailchimp's "Subscriber popup", use the "Embedded forms" option and insert that code within a popup you create yourself using a basic 'modal' technique.

Modal tutorial:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp